# Data is not getting ingested into ADX through ADF

Tags: azure

Data is not getting ingested into ADX through ADF. The following error is showing in the pipeline runs in ADF under the Monitor Section in ADF

ErrorCode=UserErrorKustoWriteFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failure status of the first blob that failed: Insufficient security permissions to execute request,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.KustoConnector,'

please help me in solving this issue.